# reconnect to database if connection restart

Tags: java, jboss, datasource

I have JBoss, and I am using JNDI to connect to database, but when database restarts, I have to restart JBoss to take new connection pool, are there any properties to do reconnection?, please help

```
 <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.2">
        <datasources>
            <datasource jta="false" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ams" pool-name="OracleDS" enabled="true" use-ccm="false">
                <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@rhhqrac01scant:1521/testingenv</connection-url>
                <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</driver-class>
                <driver>oracle</driver>
                <pool>
                    <min-pool-size>100</min-pool-size>
                    <max-pool-size>150</max-pool-size>
                    <prefill>true</prefill>
                    <flush-strategy>FailingConnectionOnly</flush-strategy>
                </pool>
                <security>
                    <user-name>ams</user-name>
                    <password>testpassword</password>
                </security>
                <validation>
                    <check-valid-connection-sql>select 1 from dual</check-valid-connection-sql>
                    <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
                    <background-validation>false</background-validation>
                </validation>
                <timeout>
                    <set-tx-query-timeout>false</set-tx-query-timeout>
                    <blocking-timeout-millis>0</blocking-timeout-millis>
                    <idle-timeout-minutes>0</idle-timeout-minutes>
                    <query-timeout>0</query-timeout>
                    <use-try-lock>0</use-try-lock>
                    <allocation-retry>0</allocation-retry>
                    <allocation-retry-wait-millis>0</allocation-retry-wait-millis>
                </timeout>
                <statement>
                    <share-prepared-statements>false</share-prepared-statements>
                </statement>
            </datasource>
            <drivers>
                <driver name="oracle" module="com.oracle.ojdbc6">
                    <xa-datasource-class>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
            </drivers>
        </datasources>
    </subsystem>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add that under your datasource tag

```
<check-valid-connection-sql>select 1</check-valid-connection-sql>
```

Comment: Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: org.jboss.as.connector.util.ParserException: IJ010061: Unexpected element: check-valid-connection-sql

Comment: which jboss version are you using?

Comment: JBoss Enterprise Application Platform version 6.4.0.GA

Comment: I checked again and I saw that you already have that config in your xml file under validation tag. So it should work but you should change your sql if you don't have table named "dual". Secondly with that configuration you will still see the connection error at first after you restarted your database. But datasource will renew all connections one by one. So you will not need to restart your server.

Comment: only put select 1 instead of select 1 from dual ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <validate-on-match>true </validate-on-match>
```

knowing that this recovers connection, but unfortunately, it will put more load on the database because it validates the connection each time the connection is checked out from the pool.